# how to remove horizontal line from barchart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to solve this problem,
use FL-CHART package

[image: this is my output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the horizontal lines by setting `drawHorizontalLine` property to **false**

Example,

```
BarChart(BarChartData(gridData: FlGridData(
                    show: true,
                    drawVerticalLine: false,
                    drawHorizontalLine: false,// this one
              )));
```

Comment: What for reverce bar(Column) issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width to `zero (0)` of that lines.

Example: `majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),`

Comment: Use fl-chart dart package